# How to check already purchased InApp purchases on ios

Tags: ios, ios5, in-app-purchase

I am working with InApp purchase, so I have implemented a working model,I have referred this

link  http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.in/2012/04/implementing-inapp-purchase-in-xcode.html.

Here when the user purchases an item I store some value in **KeyChain** and I cross check with this value to confirm that the user has purchased the item and if not I will ask the user to purchase the item.

This works, but I have **4 products** available for purchase, which can be purchased **individually**, So I thought of creating different **instances of KeyChain** and storing different passwords for these 4 products and cross check, but keyChain can only save one username and password.

So I want to know what can be the alternative for this.Also **NSUserdefaults**  will not work, because it is tied to the App bundle and whenever user deletes the app, the data is lost and so he will be asked to purchase again.

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: first of all, you should always have a "Restore Purchases" button in your application. it's a very open question, you could consider storing all purchase info in one password (nnnn would mean none of the products were purchased, ynnn would mean only the first product was purchased and so on...) but it's not a elegant solution. I'd suggest you use NSUserDefaults anyway

Comment: But if you use NSUserDefaults when you delete the app, the data in it will be wiped out

Comment: that's why you should have a restore button, StoreKit has methods that let you do this easily. In another scenario, imagine you use Keychain and the user buys a new iPhone, then what?

Comment: So you mean their is no need of KeyChain or NSUserdefaults right?

Comment: There's still need for NSUserDefaults since if you don't use that, the user would need to restore purchases every time he/she opens the app.

Comment: `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`

Answer (score 2):

If you're adding a restorable in-app purchase (non-renewable subscription, free subscription or non-consumable product), then the Store Kit API already provides the "restore transaction" functionality for you: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html

In your UI, you need add a "Restore purchases" button to your product screen that calls the `restoreCompletedTransactions` method. This is important because Apple might reject your app if you don't provide this button.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is wiped when the application is uninstalled. The keychain is safe, but it is tied to a device, not a user account (the same user account could be in multiple devices). If you want to store the receipt. store it in your server, or iCloud.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Martin, I am testing inApp purchases , I purchased one item, then I deleted the app and again reinstalled it. Now when I click on restore button, it asks for password, after entering password, nothing happens. Whether I am missing anything?.Please help me out

Comment: Hey @Daniel Martin, please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974833/behaviour-of-restoring-transactions-when-no-product-has-been-purchased-in-ios